# How do I make my discord.py bot get a user's avatar?

Tags: python, parsing, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make my discord.py bot be able to send a user's avatar into the chat when it is asked to. This is my current code:

```
if any(word in msg for word in avatar_words):
       async def avatar(ctx,*,avamember:discord.Member=None):
           userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
           await ctx.send(userAvatarUrl)
```

This code doesn't work and I'm not exactly sure why. I would also like to give the bot the ability to have the bot get a mentioned user's avatar as opposed to just the author's, but yet again I'm unsure exactly how.

Yes, I have looked around beforehand and all of the solutions I found did not work. The one shown is the only one that did not produce error messages.

Comment: Do any errors show up? Also I am not sure if avamember can be given in the message so it is a discord.member. Just for explanation; you are sending with this code a link in the chat which I am not sure if it needs the image permission and it just isn't being converted into an image

Comment: @FlexGames no errors show up, no

Comment: @FlexGames look into `Converters`. Both the user's `id` and a `@mention` will automatically be converted into a `discord.Member` instance if the argument is typehinted like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
async def avatar(ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.message.author
    em = discord.Embed(title=str(member), color=0xAE0808)
    em.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, is it using any imported content that I may need?

Comment: Describe "this doesn't work". If you would be missing some imports you'd get an `ImportError` (and it would also say which ones).

Comment: This code works perfectly for me and my network this bot is in. As Stijn said could you provide more information of the error, or some more parts of your code?

Comment: @stijndcl It's just not triggering. Whenever I say "avatar @user" in chat it doesn't activate, it doesn't even return a message into the console. It may be due to the fact that my bot is unique in that it doesn't use a command system, it reacts to pre-selected words that users type into the chat, so there's no command or prefix code to run off of, it's primarily `if any(word in msg for word in word_list):` and `if msg.startswith('word'):` code. It also all runs on the main.py file hosted on replit.com. Keep in mind I'm not very experienced with python and am just starting out.